# MySQL get 2 most recent records for each unique title

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have the following table:

```
Type        |Price   |Time      
-------------------------
Drill       | 5      | ---
Drill       | 2      | ---
Drill       | 1      | ---
Plant       | 3      | ---
Plant       | 4      | ---
Light Plant | 9      | ---
Light Plant | 21     | ---
Light Plant | 1      | ---
Light Plant | 5      | ---
```

I would like to get the 2 most recent records of each Type.
So this is the output I'm expecting:

```
Drill       | 5
Drill       | 2
Plant       | 3
Plant       | 4
Light Plant | 9
Light Plant | 21
```

I have a working solution with multiple queries i.e. each query looks for the 2 most recent records of a specific Type. Loop over all the unique Types. However, I want to do it with a single query.

Comment: *... assuming the table is ordered* there is no inherent row order in SQL tables. You need to specify a column that determines order. Do you have such a column in your table?

Comment: I do. Sorry I wasn't clear. What I meant is _assuming the table is ordered, this is the **result** I'm expecting_. I do have a column that determines order (a timestamp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I want to get the 2 most recent for each Type. The existence of any Type on the table should not affect any other one. i.e. the records of a particular type shouldn't depend on any of the other Types. Also it should be oblivious to the actual data (get the two recent ones without knowing anything about their content other than the fact they're of a particular Type)